# Double pipes in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, pipe

Is it possible to do a command in Linux with "double pipes", like this?

```
blah | blah | blah
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, as many as you like.

`$ ls -al`

gives this

```
total 25
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 nifle None 4096 2010-04-11 11:34 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 nifle root    0 2010-02-09 18:46 ..
-rw-------  1 nifle None 4581 2010-06-10 20:34 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nifle None 1150 2010-02-09 16:42 .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nifle None 3754 2010-02-09 16:42 .bashrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nifle None 1461 2010-02-09 16:42 .inputrc
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nifle None  308 2010-04-11 11:38 so.pl
```

If I pipe that through grep, sed and cut like this:
`$ ls -al | grep prof | sed 's/i/XX/g'  | cut -c 10-`
I get
`x  1 nXXfle None 1150 2010-02-09 16:42 .bash_profXXle`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use as many pipes as you want (and as long as it makes sense with the commands ;))

Comment: Strictly speaking, it doesn't even need to make sense. But it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as many pipes as long as your pass input into a command that accepts input.